# C# declaration of variable

Tags: c#, memory, declaration

I started my journey with C# but I realised that I have some problems with some basic information about memory when it comes to declaration of variables. See if I am correct.

```
int x; // I declared variable of type int, which name is x. Compiler will provide memory for it but we dont have known value of it.
x=10; // Now memory location is still the same but value now kept there is 10;

public struct Point {
    public int x, y;
}
```

Now I define a struct named Point. Beacuse struct is a value type, it again has reserved memory for it on the computer. Howewer x and y have no value.

`Now Point p1 = new Point();  // what is happening here?` Struct is not a reference type. So is this just initialization of Point variable with the default constructor without assigning values to x and y?

Second short question. When I write a code like:

```
int x = 10;
```

Can I say that I created instance of class integer which value is 10 and name x;
 I would be grateful for help.

Comment: A `struct` is a value type which always has a value (the default value of each field's type, so `0` for `int`). An explicit parameterless constructor is not allowed for this reason.

Comment: [See the spec.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: When you say int x = 10; 
You are assigning value to integer type x, no instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // what is happening here? Struct is not a reference type. So is this just initialization of Point variable with the default constructor without assigning values to x and y?

No; there are 4 possible scenarios here:

- a `class`: the memory space is wiped to all 0s, then any custom constructor is invoked, which may also involve field initializers
- a `struct` called without a custom constructor: the memory space is wiped to all 0s
- a `struct` called *with* a custom constructor: the custom constructor ***is required*** to assign all the fields
- a `struct` variable used without ever calling a constructor: this is actually a thing, but the calling code *must write to all the fields* before they can do anything else with it; since most structs do not expose their fields, this rarely works

> Second short question. When i write a code like:
>
> ```
>    int x = 10;
> ```
>
> Can i say that i created instance of class integer which value is 10 and name x; I would be grateful for help.

Not really, because *in C# terms*, `int` is not a class (it might be in IL terms). Simply: you have declared a local variable of type `int` with name `x` and assigned it the value `10`, if this is in a method. If this is a class field, then: you have declared a private instance field of type `int` named `x` with a field-initializer giving it the value of `10`.

Incidentally, you should avoid public fields in general, and mutable fields on structs. You might prefer:

```
public struct Point {
    private readonly int x, y;
    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }
    public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y'; }
}
```

This will avoid a huge range of problems.

Comment: great but i dont get what  ,,wiped to all 0s,, means :)

Comment: @user3402584 your computer has memory; every value, whether a value-type or reference-type: takes some of that memory. Imagine a value takes 20 bytes to store, for some reason (5 integers, as an example). Now set the 20 bytes that represent that value ***all to zero***. That is what it means. In the case of integers, the 4 bytes [0 0 0 0] represent `0`. In the case of references the 4-bytes (32-bit) or 8 bytes (64-bit) of zero are also known as: `null`

Comment: hmmm,,,Now set the 20 bytes that represent that value all to zero'' U mean i set 5 integers to 0 ? I dont get it, srry

Comment: Your fourth bullet can be a little weaker - if you write to one field, you can at least read that field.

Comment: @user3402584 the integers **are the bytes**. The bytes **are the integers**. They are one and the same. What you think of as an `int` is just your interpretation of the value of 4 bytes (`int` === `Int32` === 4 bytes). What gets *really* interesting is that different machines can actually represent represent the same number differently, hence "big-endian" vis "little-endian". But since Itaniums never really became big, most people don't need to worry about that. In either event: [0 0 0 0] is always `0`, regardless of CPU architecture.

Comment: @Rawling indeed, yes; although since it is very rare to expose fields, this is largely moot anyway ;p

Answer (score 1):

In C# the default struct constructor sets the struct memory to 0, effectively setting all variables to their default values.

In case of `int`s, it will be `0`. For reference types, it will result in `null`.
(in other words, for any type `T` it will be `default(T)`).

Note that when you write a custom constructor in a struct, you *must* initialize all member fields.

Comment: what does memory to 0 mean?

Comment: If you know C, imagine calling `memset(&theStruct, 0, sizeof(typeOfTheStruct))`

Answer (score 1):

When you write
`int x;`

this is similar to 
`Point p1 = new Point();` (considering Point structure is already defined)

in both the cases all integer variables will have default value of 0 and not null, which is is basically what is used in C# to denote 'nothing' and can be assigned only to reference types.

As well, in c# everything is a class, so when you write
`int x = 10;`

you are creating an instance of class `Int32`, though the run time will handle this as value type instead of ref type, as special case.

Same is true for other basic types like, `Long, DateTime` and few others